# jQuery Ajax Call Pass Parameter

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for on here...

`NULL` is passed to my ASP.net controller - `iid` does have a value.

```
function Dismiss(iid) {
    $.ajax({url: '@Url.Action("DismissNotification")', type: 'GET',Data: {id:iid}, success: function(result){
            $('#' + id).hidden();
    }});
}

[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public bool DismissNotification(string id)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
    {
        _notificationService.Dismiss(id);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings property in which the client sends data to server is called `data` , not `Data`

This should work

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("DismissNotification")',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { id: iid },
    success: function (result) {
        console.log('result',result);
}});
```

You can also use the `$.get` method as well

```
$.get('@Url.Action("DismissNotification")', { id: iid }, function (result) {
    console.log('r', result);
});
```